# Swinging image animation, need help to fix. Still OPEN

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

So I've got this [JsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rksh1tdv/) here and it works, only problem is, I need the Javascript to function, for some reason my website wont detect it as is.

Here's what is in the Fiddle.

HTML

```
<div class="swing" style="background-color:#transparent;">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.swing {
-webkit-perspective:300px;
-moz-perspective: 300px;
-ms-perspective: 300px;
perspective: 300px;
}
.swing img {
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
```

And the Javascript

```
$('.swing img').mouseenter(function(event)
{
var sign = event.currentTarget;
sign.rotationX = 0;
TweenMax.to(sign, 0.2, { rotationX:-20, ease:Power1.easeOut, onUpdate:onUpdate, onUpdateParams:["{self}"]});
TweenMax.to(sign, 0.4, { rotationX:8, ease:Power1.easeInOut, onUpdate:onUpdate, onUpdateParams:["{self}"], delay:0.2 });
TweenMax.to(sign, 3, { rotationX:0, ease:Elastic.easeOut, onUpdate:onUpdate, onUpdateParams:["{self}"], delay:0.6 });
});
function onUpdate(tween)
{
var target = tween.target;
target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform = target.style.msTransform = target.style.MozTransform = 'rotateX('+(target.rotationX)+'deg)';
}
```

Comment: If you post your non-working HEAD section we should be able to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need jQuery script reference.
You can get it from [Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript needs to wait until the DOM has finished loading, wrap it in:

```
$(function() {
  // code
});
```

Comment: And I presume you are putting it into the head as a link to a <script> and not raw code?

Comment: $(function() {
  // <script src=".JS Link"></script>
});

Comment: No, inside the script file you are linking to wrap the JS above in it

Comment: Can you post your HEAD section in your question. It's hard to say what the problem is otherwise